# Rails not using correct controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a view  with the following code:

```
<%= form_for(@stock,:url=>{:action=>"buyback"},:html=>{:class=>"form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

My routes.rb file shows:

```
post '/stocks/buyback'
```

When I click the submit button of the form, it does not trigger the method buyback of the controller but instead update.

The log file shows:

```
Started PUT "/stocks/buyback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-22 19:46:07 +0800
Processing by StocksController#update as HTML
```

Its triggering the controller method Update instead of buyback. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<%= form_for(@stock,:url=>{:action=>"buyback"},:method => :post, :html=>{:class=>"form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```